# How can I build a Docker image in an Azure Devops pipeline while specifying the architecture as linux/arm64/v8?

Tags: c#, docker, azure-devops, raspberry-pi, azure-pipelines

I currently have an Azure Devops build pipeline that creates an image build on the amd64 architecture. When I try to run this on a Raspberry Pi it fails with an error stating that the image needs to be built using linux/arm64/v8 architecture.

Here is my YAML

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - 'XXXXX/*'

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  dockerrepo: 'xxxxxxx'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'xxxxx Container Registry'
        repository: $(dockerrepo)
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        Dockerfile: '*/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

The Docker file builds  c# .net6 console app.

How can I get the pipeline to build the image with a specified architecture so that it can run on a Raspberry Pi 4?

EDIT

Also tried supplying platform argument as advised by @szombati_attila but this fails to create an image failing with an invalid argument error

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build image
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'xxxx Container Registry'
        repository: $(dockerrepo)
        command: build
        arguments: '--platform linux/arm64/v8'
        Dockerfile: '*/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: 'xxxx Container Registry'
        repository: $(dockerrepo)
        command: push
        Dockerfile: '*/Dockerfile'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Comment: It's **architecture** - not "architacture"....

Comment: As the error message indicates, your issue could be resulted from the argument. According to this doc for [docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64), have you tried to edit your argument with  `--platform linux/arm64v8`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting the `buildAndPush` into two different commands. Because you cannot add any additional argument when you are using the `buildAndPush` command. This is because the `buildAndPush` command is a combination of two docker commands (build and push) and the additional argument input would be ambiguous.

After the split, you will have two tasks and the `arguments` now can be added to the `build` task.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: BuildDockerContainer
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: registry
    repository: repo
    tags: latest
    arguments: add any label that you want here and supported by Docker (--platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64)

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: PushDockerImageToRegisitry
  inputs:
    command: push
    containerRegistry: registry
    repository: repo
    tags: latest
```

Documentations:

Azure DevOps Docker-V2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml

Docker platform flag:

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/